# Mapping entities with composite keys

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I am working on converting a legacy system to use hibernate (version 3.3.x) instead of using hand crafted SQL. I have run in to some problems mapping my datamodel that pertians to composite keys. I've created a solution I think works, but I am not overly fond of it. Hence, I would like to see how the diagram below could/should be mapped and see if I am on the "right" track.

[image]

In the diagram StuffTypes is a pretty static table that don't change (no inserts or updates). Parent is the only table that currently has a DAO class associated to it (the others should be persisted when the parent instance is). Stuff has a StuffType and a number of SubStuff associated with it. Finally, SubStuff is just a many to many mapping table between Stuff and StuffTypes.

What is the best way of mapping these entities to Java objects using annotations?

Comment: Are you storing special things in SubStuff or additional things in SubStuff that are not present in Stuff. If not than a much clear/simple design would be to have a recursive relationship on Stuff. Stuff would then contain - parentId, stuffTypeId, parentStuffId and drop the SubStuff table altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I often refer to the section [3.2 Primary Keys through -ToOne Relationships](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Primary_Keys_through_OneToOne_Relationships) of the JPA Wiki Book. And read also [3.1 Composite Primary Keys](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Composite_Primary_Keys).

Answer (score 0):

Adding a primary key `stuff_id` to the Stuff table and another primary key `substuff_id` to SubStuff is less complicated. Composite keys are possible, of course. If seen solutions where @Embeddable classes have been introduced to model the composite keys.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate Reference is your best bet. Try this, [Mapping Entities with Composite Keys](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2177).